# How to make auto scrolling wx.grid table?

Tags: python, wxwidgets

python 2.7 I have `wx.grid` table. How can I do vertical scrolling?

I tried:

```
MakeCellVisible(rows,cols)
```

and

```
SetGridCursor(rows, cols)
```

but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
grid_widget.Scroll(row, column)
```

---

Edit: Here you have a working example:

[image]

That was produced with:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid
#
class Button(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, source):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, size=(100,100))
        self.source = source
        self.pos = 0 
        self.button = wx.Button(self, label='0')
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onbutton, self.button)
        self.Show()

    def onbutton(self, evt):
        self.pos += 1
        self.source.grid.Scroll(self.pos, self.pos) 
        self.button.SetLabel(str(self.pos))  

class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Grid", size=(350,250))
        self.grid = grid.Grid(self)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(20, 20)
        self.but = Button(None, self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.PySimpleApp()
    frame = Frame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Just try to use grids function MakeCellVisible(row, col)