# How to sync the scrollbars of two grids in wx

Tags: python, grid, scrollbar, synchronization, wxwidgets

One custom wx.frame is created to contain a splitter window with two grid controls inside. It's used to compare the data in each of the grid. At this point the scrollbar of two grids need to support sync scroll.

Questions:

1. How to get these two grid's scroll event? I have tried to bin the wx.EVT_SCROLL event at the frame but failed. I also try to bind the scroll event in the custom grid control, it's failed too.
2. How to sync scroll the scrollbar of the two grids? An answer of a relative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8665633/how-to-make-auto-scrolling-wx-grid-table) mentioned to use gridInstance.Scroll(row, col) to scroll the grid client window. But it doesn't contain how to sync the scrollbar.

Many thanks for any suggestion.

The init method of the custom frame

```
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, title='', size=(640,480))
        main_panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
        self.TBFLAGS = ( wx.TB_HORIZONTAL| wx.NO_BORDER| wx.TB_FLAT)
        self.controller = None
        self.isSyncScroll = True

        #hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        gsizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(rows = 1,
                                                    cols = 1,
                                                    vgap = 2,
                                                    hgap = 2)
        gsizer.AddGrowableRow(0)
        gsizer.AddGrowableCol(0)
        self.tb = self.init_toolbar()
        (sub_panel0, sub_panel1) = self.init_splitter(main_panel)
        self.grid0 = self.init_grid(sub_panel0)
        self.grid1 = self.init_grid(sub_panel1)
        self.init_status_bar()

        gsizer.Add(main_panel, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(gsizer)

        ico = wx.Icon(u'Compare.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ICO)
        self.SetIcon(ico)
        self.Maximize()

        #can't catch the scroll event at the frame
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnScroll, self.grid0)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnScroll)
        #self.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLL, self.OnScroll, id=self.grid0.GetId())
```

Comment: Why don't you put all the data in the same grid, side by side ?

Comment: The customer what this... so, it's have to. The data column will compare like winmerge and add dummy column to match align the equal columns.

Comment: All the other features are implemented except sync scroll the scrollbars of the two grid. It's seems a common problem, there is already [someone asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269558/wxgrid-detecting-scroll-event) how to detect the scroll event. I could only find out how to bind mouse wheel event from the grid window.

Answer (score 8):

The following code gets 2 scrollbars moving together when you grab one or the other.

Python version 2.7.3 & wxpython 2.9.4.0 & windows Xp.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Grid", size=(350, 250))
        self.grid = grid.Grid(self)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(20, 20)


class ScrollSync(object):
    def __init__(self, frame1, frame2):
        self.frame1 = frame1
        self.frame2 = frame2
        self.frame1.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.onScrollWin1)
        self.frame2.grid.Bind(wx.EVT_SCROLLWIN, self.onScrollWin2)

    def onScrollWin1(self, event):
        if event.Orientation == wx.SB_HORIZONTAL:
            self.frame2.grid.Scroll(event.Position, -1)
        else:
            self.frame2.grid.Scroll(-1, event.Position)
        event.Skip()

    def onScrollWin2(self, event):
        if event.Orientation == wx.SB_HORIZONTAL:
            self.frame1.grid.Scroll(event.Position, -1)
        else:
            self.frame1.grid.Scroll(-1, event.Position)
        event.Skip()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame1 = Frame(None)
    frame1.Show()
    frame2 = Frame(None)
    frame2.Show()
    ScrollSync(frame1, frame2)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Here is another version that uses a timer to check and set scroll positions, so it cover any type of scroll change.

```
import wx
import wx.grid as grid


class Frame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, -1, "Grid", size=(350, 250))
        self.grid = grid.Grid(self)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(20, 20)


class ScrollSync(wx.EvtHandler):
    def __init__(self, frame1, frame2):
        super(ScrollSync, self).__init__()
        self.frame1 = frame1
        self.frame2 = frame2
        self.frame1ScrollPos = self.getFrame1Pos()
        self.frame2ScrollPos = self.getFrame2Pos()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer)
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.timer.Start(20)

    def onTimer(self, event):
        if not self.frame1 or not self.frame2:
            self.timer.Stop()
            return
        if self.frame1ScrollPos != self.getFrame1Pos():
            self.frame1ScrollPos = self.getFrame1Pos()
            self.frame2.grid.Scroll(self.frame1ScrollPos)
        elif self.frame2ScrollPos != self.getFrame2Pos():
            self.frame2ScrollPos = self.getFrame2Pos()
            self.frame1.grid.Scroll(self.frame2ScrollPos)

    def getFrame1Pos(self):
        horizontal = self.frame1.grid.GetScrollPos(wx.SB_HORIZONTAL)
        vertical = self.frame1.grid.GetScrollPos(wx.SB_VERTICAL)
        return horizontal, vertical

    def getFrame2Pos(self):
        horizontal = self.frame2.grid.GetScrollPos(wx.SB_HORIZONTAL)
        vertical = self.frame2.grid.GetScrollPos(wx.SB_VERTICAL)
        return horizontal, vertical


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    frame1 = Frame(None)
    frame1.Show()
    frame2 = Frame(None)
    frame2.Show()
    ScrollSync(frame1, frame2)
    app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: Thank you it's work, but the mouse wheel, page up/down and line up/down events still need to handle separately.