# How to create a wxpython notebook with 2 panels splitted horizontally?

Tags: python, split, wxpython, wxnotebook

I'm trying to build something like below:

[image]

It's a notebook with 2 panels, split horizontally. The panel on top is also split into 2, each split containing a wx.grid object.

I have tried the code below, but 2 grids on top panel do not show up:

```
class NoteBook(wx.Notebook):

    def __init__(self, parent, pages):

        wx.Notebook.__init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, style= wx.BK_DEFAULT)
        self.parent = parent
        page = "TEST"

        self.splitter_window = wx.SplitterWindow(self)

        self.AddPage(self.splitter_window, page)
        title_name = page[1:]

        grid_panel = wx.Panel(self.splitter_window, style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        grid_splitter = wx.SplitterWindow(grid_panel)

        grid_panel_1 = wx.Panel(grid_splitter, style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        grid1 = grid_maker.GridArea(grid_panel_1)
        grid1.CreateGrid(page) #create the grid 1
        grid1.addToGrid(page) #adding some data to grid 1
        binder = cxt_functions.GridFunctions(self, grid1) #bind some functions to grid1
        binder.BindCrewGridMenu()            

        grid_panel_2 = wx.Panel(grid_splitter, style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        grid2 = grid_maker.CreateGrid(grid_panel_2) #create the grid 1
        grid2.addToGrid(page) #adding some data to grid 1


        grid_splitter.SplitVertically(grid_panel_1, grid_panel_2, 100)

        grid_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        grid_sizer.Add(grid1, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 7)
        grid_sizer.Add(grid2, 0, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 7)

        grid_panel.SetSizer(grid_sizer)

        chart_panel = wx.Panel(self.splitter_window, style=wx.BORDER_THEME)
        line_chart = bar_line.CanvasPanel(chart_panel, title_name)
        line_chart.draw()


        self.splitter_window.SplitHorizontally(grid_panel, chart_panel, 500)

        p_sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        p_sizer.Add(self, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALL, 7)    
        self.parent.SetSizer(p_sizer)


        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.parent, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)
```

What is wrong above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what's going on with your code as it's not exactly runnable, so I put together my own version:

```
import wx
import wx.grid as gridlib

########################################################################
class RegularPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetBackgroundColour("pink")


########################################################################
class GridPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.grid = gridlib.Grid(self, style=wx.BORDER_SUNKEN)
        self.grid.CreateGrid(25,8)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(self.grid, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


########################################################################
class MainPanel(wx.Panel):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)

        notebook = wx.Notebook(self)

        page = wx.SplitterWindow(notebook)
        notebook.AddPage(page, "Splitter")
        hSplitter = wx.SplitterWindow(page)

        panelOne = GridPanel(hSplitter)
        panelTwo = GridPanel(hSplitter)
        hSplitter.SplitVertically(panelOne, panelTwo)
        hSplitter.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        panelThree = RegularPanel(page)
        page.SplitHorizontally(hSplitter, panelThree)
        page.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        sizer.Add(notebook, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)

########################################################################
class MainFrame(wx.Frame):
    """"""

    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor"""
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title="Nested Splitters",
                          size=(800,600))
        panel = MainPanel(self)
        self.Show()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App(False)
    frame = MainFrame()
    app.MainLoop()
```

This is based on one of my [nested SplitterWindow tutorial](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/10/18/wxpython-an-introduction-to-splitterwindows/). I hope that helps you figure out what's going on in your own code.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to place it on a notebook, which is on a Frame. How to adjust it?

Comment: Well all you'd want to do is add a Notebook and make it the parent of the first splitter. I adjusted the code slightly.

Comment: Ok, I got it worked. Mike, please show me how to synchronously scroll the 2 grids on top panel, I have tried everything but couldn't get it work. I'll be grateful. Best regards

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy way to accomplish that. The closest I've found that's ready made is the answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15870426/how-to-sync-the-scrollbars-of-two-grids-in-wx

Comment: Would you use a "vertically splitted window" or "2 separate panels" for those 2 grids? which one is more convenient?

Comment: @MikeDriscoll: I like the code formatting.  Very clean, easy on the eyes.  Kudos.